# Wireless issue in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, live-usb

I am using ubuntu 16.04 on my Sony Vaio laptop, and today i have installed ubuntu in dell latitude e6430s laptop from same live usb. I am facing issue with wireless network. Can anybody help me with this ?

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit      Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
       DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
         Subsystem: Dell 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [1028:057d]
       Kernel driver in use: e1000e
       Kernel modules: e1000e

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino        Ultimate-N 6300 [8086:422b] (rev 35)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 3x3 AGN [8086:1121]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Here is the output of rfkill list

```
       rfkill list
       1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: yes
       2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: yes
       3: phy0: Wireless LAN
       Soft blocked: no
       Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: What is the issue? Please describe a little more.

Comment: I am unable to turn on my wireless network from settings, and currently i am connected on LAN.

Comment: Are you seeing any error/message? Have you installed all the drivers for wireless interfaces?

Comment: In Software&Updates when i navigate to additional drivers there i found
Unkown:Unknown

This device is using an alternative driver.
*Using processor microcode firmware for intel CPUs from intel-microcode (proprietary)
*Do not use the device.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Have a look on output @Pilot

Comment: OK, then please also add the output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: rfkill list
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: Please add it TO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: There must be a hardware switch on the laptop. Or you may need to reset BIOS to defaults.

Comment: Thank you so much Pilot! I switch on side of leptop, and turned it to on. Problem Solved.